# Was not ale to reach hosted site through IP address?

Tags: apache, drupal-7

**SOLVED**
I'm hosting a small site for my team.. 
Software stack: Drupal 7 over XAMPP (Apache,php,mysql)
I was able to reach the site through http://hostname/portalname but not able to through ipaddress 
http://ipaddress/portalname gives me Error Code 10060: Connection timeout

**SOLUTION**
IT was proxy issue.. Once my browser proxy was disabled, I was able to access the site through IP address..

Comment: if you `ping hostname` do you get a reply from the ip address you expect?  the hostname may have been linked with another ip address because the hosting package changed to another machine for example.

Comment: Sorry My bad it was a proxy issue... Sorry for the delay in responding... When i disabled the proxy in my browser i was able to reach the site through the ipaddress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT was proxy issue.. Once my browser proxy was disabled, I was able to access the site through IP address..

Answer (score 0):

Apache can serve websites for multiple domains from one server via [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/) (or "vhosts"). It uses the hostname being requested to determine which site to serve up to a particular user. Here's some [more detail about XAMPP's vhost configuration](http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/).